# Placing arrows nicely

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I want to draw a diagram like this:
[image]

I want α ends at F and β starts from F (horizontally), is there an easy to fix my code:

````
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3em]
            &\EuScript{C} \arrow{dd}[description]{F}   \ar[dl, "p"']\arrow[dr, "p"] & \\
            \EuScript{D}\ar[dr, "L"']\arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, "\beta"'] &&\EuScript{D}\ar[dl, "R"]\arrow[Rightarrow, to=U, "\alpha"']  \\
            &\EuScript{E}. &
\end{tikzcd}```
````

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just place the `F` inside the matrix itself but as a label along the line?

Comment: Just want to be symmetric...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possibility: Give a `name` to the label F, then add the arrow from a cell to F and from F to a cell. You can adjust the atart or end angle with start/end anchor

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3em]
& C\ar{dd}[description,name=f]{F}\ar{ld}[swap]{p}\ar{dr}{p}\\
D\ar{rd}[swap]{L} && D\ar{ld}{R}\\
& E\mathrlap{.}
\ar[Rightarrow,from=2-3,to=f, end anchor={[yshift=-0.1ex]}]{}[swap]{\alpha}
\ar[Rightarrow,from=f,to=2-1, start anchor={[yshift=-0.1ex]}]{}[swap]{\beta}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that if you simply write `E.` in the bottom, then this cell do not look centered. It is better to use `\mathrlap{.}` from `mathtools` package

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's simpler than already proposed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,euscript,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3em]
&
\EuScript{C} \arrow[dd,"F" description] \arrow[dl, "p"'] \arrow[dr, "p"] &
\\
\EuScript{D} \arrow[dr, "L"'] &
\arrow[l,Rightarrow, "\beta"'] \arrow[d] &
\EuScript{D} \arrow[dl, "R"] \arrow[l,Rightarrow, "\vphantom{\beta}\alpha"']  \\
&
\EuScript{E} &
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3em]
&
\EuScript{C} \arrow[dd,"F" description,pos=0.3] \arrow[dl, "p"'] \arrow[dr, "p"] &
\\
\EuScript{D} \arrow[dr, "L"'] &
\arrow[l,Rightarrow, "\beta"'] \arrow[d] &
\EuScript{D} \arrow[dl, "R"] \arrow[l,Rightarrow, "\vphantom{\beta}\alpha"']  \\
&
\EuScript{E} &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the second case, I move the label so it's not confused with a node. I also added a `\vphantom` so the labels over the double arrows are at the same level.

Comment: That's really great, especially your second code. Sorry I can't take both, I already took Luis Turcio's answer, hope you don't mind.